# how to config nginx link to docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, iptables

need help,spend more than 30 hours...realy need help...thanks

> system:centos 7

i have **nginx** and **docker container (ps:gitlab)**,i have problem with connection with nginx - docker container(gitlab),i get nothing when use git.xxx.com:8800 try to connect,i think is problem with configuration, here is my config:

> docker container(gitlab):

```
    sudo docker run -d \
    --hostname git.xxx.com \
    --publish 127.0.0.1:8800:80 \
    --publish 127.0.0.1:23:22 \
    --name gitlab \
    --memory 4gb \
    --cpus 2 \
    --restart always \
    --volume /Volumes/docker_gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /Volumes/docker_gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /Volumes/docker_gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://git.xxx.com:8800'; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=23;" \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

> nginx:

```
 server {
        listen *:8800;
        server_name git.xxx.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://172.17.0.2:80;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
}
```

> iptables -s:

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

> try to test the url connection in centos:

```
curl -vvv 'http://127.0.0.1:8800'
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 8800 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8800 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8800
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

> ***just done*** ! Update,when you use docker run.. docker will write iptables rule to the /etc/sysconfig/iptables,so dont need to write rule manualy
>
> docker container(gitlab):

```
    sudo docker run -d \
    --hostname git.xxx.com \
    --publish 30000:30000 \
    --publish 30001:22 \
    --name gitlab \
    --memory 4gb \
    --cpus 2 \
    --restart always \
    --volume /Volumes/docker_gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /Volumes/docker_gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /Volumes/docker_gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://git.xxx.com:30000'; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=30001;" \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

> nginx: dont need to change anything

Comment: solution is on the *update*